# Why is the right-click menu on the taskbar missing for some icons?

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar

This has happened to me once before. I attempted to pin Eclipse (Java IDE) to the taskbar, and for some reason there are now 2 icons there. Neither of them have a right-click menu, so I cannot remove them.

Any way to get rid of them?

Comment: As a workaround you might clear all pinned programs, as explained here: [How to remove Store from taskbar](http://superuser.com/questions/741425/how-to-remove-store-from-taskbar)

Comment: Yea that works, doesnt take too long to pin stuff anyhow. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: You can also do a small trick so that you don't have 2 eclipse icons in the taskbar when you run eclipse. But that is another question.

Answer (score 1):

I just accidentally realized that every application, that has the text "**uninstaller**" in the executable file name, will not have the proper context menu, that is usually displayed on every running application icon on the taskbar (I noticed this because I couldn't pin the icon of the "ZSoft Uninstaller" to the taskbar, which executable file name was "Uninstaller.exe"). I guess this is one of many Microsoft's "brilliant" bulletproof ideas to protect users from themselves...

Another reason for this can be the [misconfiguration in the Group Policy Editor](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/7c0a568b-b960-4a08-a1d2-cf76021cc570/start-menu-taskbar-pinning-disappeared).

> Click star menu and type gpedit.msc in the search box, press enter. Then you will see Local Group Policy Editor form.
>   Click User Configuration ->Adiministrative Templates ->start menu and taskbar.
>   Find Remove pinned programs from the taskbar and Remove pinned programs list from the start menu in the setting list.
>   Have these two setting been setting to enable? If so, change the settings to disable or not configured, this will let the “pin” item show again.

Yet another reason for this can be [removing the shortcut arrow on link file (.lnk) icons](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/pin-to-task-bar/dc64a646-b3c4-4e77-906d-a464916e920b).

> To resolve the missing or lost “Open file location” entry, the IsShortcut registry value and the file associations for shortcuts has to be fixed.
>   Run Registry Editor (regedit.exe).
>   Navigate to the following registry key:
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile
>   Right click on the right pane, and select New -> String Value (REG_SZ) to create a new registry value.
>   Name the new registry value as IsShortcut . No value data required.
>   Restart the computer.
>   If you already delete and other registry keys to remove shortcut arrows you must to do the same for all of them...

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Best if you post the answers here (at least in summary form) rather than rely on a link which may go stale.

Comment: you're right, I added the referenced steps inline.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

Quoting an answer I gave in a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/741425/how-to-remove-store-from-taskbar):

> In case you can't remove some pinned app, you might want to clear everything and start fresh.
>
> 1. Open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-8).
> 2. Type or paste the following commands, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> each time:
>
>    ```
>    del /f "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*.lnk"
>    for /f "tokens=1" %G in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband" ^| findstr /i /c:"Favorites"') do reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband" /v "%~G" /f
>    taskkill /im explorer.exe >nul
>    taskkill /im explorer.exe /f >nul
>    start explorer.exe
>    ```

### References

- [Taskbar Pinned Apps - Reset and Clear in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9610-taskbar-pinned-apps-reset-clear-windows-8-a.html)